# Как без <string.h> заставить находить код все длинные слова в строке и забивать их звездочками?

Tags: c

Я дошел до этапа ,когда я запоминаю строку в массив и считаю сколько там символов. А как определить без <string.h> самые длинные слова(их может быть несколько)?То есть запомнить их начальный индекс и максимальную длину.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {

char text[101];

gets_s(text);

int i,sim = 0;
for (i = 0; ; i++) {
if (text[i] == '\0') { break; }
sim++;
}
printf("sim=%d\n", sim);
}

 

``
   


----------
```

Comment: Такой простенький совет - сначала пройдите и найдите максимальную длину, а потом делайте второй проход и, найдя слово такой длины, заменяйте его звездочками... Как найти максимальную длину, проблем нет? Нашли слово, его длину, сравнили с последней найденной максимальной длиной. Больше? Перезаписали. Меньше или такая же? идем дальше...

Comment: А, да! как определить длину слова? Исходить из того, что слово - это только буквы. Встретили не букву - все, слово закончилось, считаем длину..